# AttributeError: 'Api' object has no attribute 'record'

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a RESTful API server using Flask. I use flask_restful library for the API. This is my `__init__` code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='views')
app = Api(app, prefix='/api')
web = Api(app)

from app import routes
```

But when I run `flask run` on the terminal, this happens:

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 115, in init_app
    app.record(self._deferred_blueprint_init)
AttributeError: 'Api' object has no attribute 'record'
```

I've googled the error and all of them are about `App object`, not `Api object`.

And, somehow, the `app` on `from app import routes` is underlined with `unresolved import`.

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Maybe you meant api = Api(app, prefix='/api')

Comment: @DarkKnight Ah, yes, I think that's the right one. Thanks!